# MYSQL server fails while installing

Tags: mysql, windows, installation, failed-installation

Screenshot while changing log on to local in service then starting the server:
[image: Screenshot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41tkO.png)

Here is the log:

```
Beginning configuration step: Stopping Server [if necessary]
Ended configuration step: Stopping Server [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating firewall
Adding firewall rule for MySQL57 on port 3306.
Successfully added firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating firewall

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service [if necessary]
Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database [if necessary]
Deleting Data folder shipped
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --Initialize-insecure
Running process: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" --initialize-insecure=on --console
Waiting for the server stops: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" --initialize-insecure=on --console
2017-04-15T06:26:24.188171Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-04-15T06:26:24.188171Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2017-04-15T06:26:29.144031Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2017-04-15T06:26:29.946540Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2017-04-15T06:26:30.159610Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'innodbclustertypeselection=0.0'
2017-04-15T06:26:30.160610Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

The attempt to initialize the database Failed
Ended configuration step: Initializing Database [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Starting Server
Starting MySQL as a service
```

Provided screenshot (during this process of installation my firewall and defender was turned off)

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you work on Windows, try the following.

If you don't need a cluster installation you must remove or comment cluster configuration variables from my.ini file, commonly this file is located in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini

Variables commented in my.ini file

```
...

# Indicates how is the InnoDB Cluster configured as (Classic, Sandbox, Master or Slave).
#innodbclustertypeselection=0.0

# Indicates how is the InnoDB Cluster is/will be named.
#innodbclustername=0.0

# Indicates how many instances will the InnoDB cluster sandbox will have.
#innodbclusterinstances=0.0

# Holds the InnoDB Cluster Username.
#innodbclusterusername=0.0

# Indicates the InnoDB Cluster URI.
#innodbclusteruri=0.0

# Indicates the InnoDB Cluster Port.
#innodbclusterport=0.0
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Worked for me. Strange thing: I used the same Installer on my local dev-machine (Windows 7) and finally on a Windows Server 2008 R2 - No problems on Win 7, problem above on 2008 R2.... I removed the values mentioned, cleared the data directory and ran `mysqld --initialize --console` - finally mysql was able to start.

Comment: ps.: The Installer is also net reliable beside "default" data-directories. When changing the path in the wizzard, several paths in my.ini keep pointing to the default, which will not work.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the MySQL installer, according to this [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85954)

If you're doing a new installation of version 5.7.11+, you will encounter this issue because the config file included with the installer has options not supported by version 5.7. I encountered this bug when installing 5.7.18, which is the latest version as of today.

You will have to follow David Aldana's solution of removing the `innodbcluster*` options from your configuration file as well as removing the 
`plugin_load` option which is set to `0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade MySQL Installer to latest version. In version 1.4.20.0 bug is fixed.
I hope this helps someone.

[image: MySQL Instaler V.1.4.20.0]

[image: Screenshot of newest version of MySQL Installer]